# How to add text and a more correct zigzag-line to a figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, floats, tikz-arrows

I have now spend hours by creating this figure - without luck.

I have tried different types of `tikz`, `pstricks` and `multido` usepackages.

My biggest problem is to add text, to add a more correct zigzag line and to add the two dashed lines.

[image]

My code look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,-] (0,0) -- (4.5,0);
\draw[thick,-] (0,0) -- (0,4.5);
\draw[thick,-] (0,0) -- (-4.5,0);
\draw[thick,-] (0,0) -- (0,-4.5);
\draw (0,0) .. controls (0,2) and (2,2) .. (4,2);
\draw (-4,-3) .. controls (-2,-3) and (0,-2) .. (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get this figure:
[image]

Comment: Hint: you can use a single command for the x axis. `\draw (-4.5,0)node[left]{\text{foo}} --(4.5,0)node[right]{\text{foo}}`

Comment: I see. Thanks. But if I add the whole text, it will be a long line. Can I divide this into two lines? And do you know how to make the dashed lines?

Comment: @A.F. I have added a small part about the line properties. Enjoy. :D

Comment: Thank you again. I have one question for you (see below). Thank you so much, Alenanno!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple solution with Tikz. You could do it with plots but I think it's easier to do it this way.

The "plot" curve is a simple edge drawn with the command
`\draw (-4.5,-3) edge[out=0,in=180,looseness=1.5] (4.5,3);`.

As you can see the starting and the ending point are symmetrical. The control options inside of edge specify where the edge comes out (0 degrees) and where it goes in (180 degrees). The looseness controls the curvature: 1 is default, 0 is a straight line, and the more you increase the number the more accentuated it will become.

[image: figure 1]

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    nodeax/.style={
        text centered,
        text width=2.5cm
    },
    every path/.style={
            thick
        }
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}

%X and Y axis and relative nodes
\draw (-4.5,0) node[nodeax,left] {Expectations failed} -- (4.5,0)  node[nodeax,right] {Expectations exceeded}; % X Axis
\draw (0,-4.5) node[nodeax,below] {Dissatisfied} -- (0,4.5) node[nodeax,above] {Confirmation satisfied}; % Y Axis

% "plot"
\draw (-4.5,-3) edge[out=0,in=180,looseness=1.5] (4.5,3);

% dashed lines and relative nodes
\draw[dashed] (-1,-4.5) -- (-1,4.5) node[left, anchor=east, xshift=-1em] {Discomfirmation};
\draw[dashed] (1,-4.5) -- (1,4.5) 
    node[right, anchor=west, xshift=1em] {Affirmation} 
    node[nodeax,pos=0.3,left, xshift=-8em] {(Difference between perfomance and expectations)};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

By the way, the dashed line is done adding `dashed` to the path options, but there are more:

[image: edges figure]

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}        
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    y=.5cm,
    every node/.style=midway, above, font=\scriptsize
    ]

\draw[densely dashdotted] (0,9) -- (5,9) node {densely dashdotted};
\draw[densely dotted] (0,8) -- (5,8) node {densely dotted};
\draw[densely dashed] (0,7) -- (5,7) node {densely dashed};

\draw[loosely dashdotted] (0,6) -- (5,6) node {loosely dashdotted};
\draw[loosely dotted] (0,5) -- (5,5) node {loosely dotted};
\draw[loosely dashed] (0,4) -- (5,4) node {loosely dashed};

\draw[dashdotted] (0,3) -- (5,3) node {dashdotted};
\draw[dotted] (0,2) -- (5,2) node {dotted};
\draw[dashed] (0,1) -- (5,1) node {dashed};
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0) node {normal};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One question: If I would like to give more space or change the textbook around "Expectations exceed/failed" how do I do that?

Comment: @A.F. Do you mean the space around the text?

Comment: If I would like to add a word or two and only want it to be on two lines, not three. How do I do that? Does that makes sense?

Comment: Ah yes, I got it now. In the `\tikzset` command in the preamble, increase `text width` to your preferred length. It can be in `mm`, `cm`, `em`, `pt`, etc, but I advise using `cm` because 1cm is much larger than 1pt, so you don't need to type `23454pt`. :D

Answer (score 3):

Done with MetaPost. The dashed lines are drawn thanks to the `dashed` operator:

```
for k = u, -u: draw (k, ymin) -- (k, ymax) dashed evenly; endfor
```

See [the MetaPost manual](http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf), p. 37 to learn how to personalize the dash pattern at will.

The curve is drawn by the following simple line:

```
draw A{right} .. origin{dir 80} .. B{right};
```

The instructions between braces indicates the direction of the tangent, specified by an angle in degrees (`right` is an alias for `dir 0`).

Note that the [`hobby`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) package for `tikz` provides features similar to those of MetaPost for the construction of Bezier curves.

```
input latexmp; setupLaTeXMP(mode=rerun, textextlabel=enable);
numeric u, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax; 
u = cm; xmax = -xmin = ymax = -ymin = 4.5u;
pair A, B; A = (xmin, -3u); B = (xmax, 2u);
beginfig(1);
  draw (xmin, 0) -- (xmax, 0);
  draw (0, ymin) -- (0, ymax);
  for k = u, -u: draw (k, ymin) -- (k, ymax) dashed evenly; endfor
  draw A{right} .. origin{dir 80} .. B{right};
  label.lft("\begin{tabular}{c}Expectations\\ failed \end{tabular}", (xmin, 0));
  label.rt("\begin{tabular}{c}Expectations\\ exceeded \end{tabular}", (xmax, 0));
  label.bot("Dissatisfied", (0, ymin));
  label.top("\begin{tabular}{c}\textbf{Confirmation}\\Satisfied\end{tabular}", (0, ymax));
  label.top("\textbf{Disconfirmation}", (.4[xmin,-u], ymax));
  label.top("\textbf{Affirmation}", (.5[u,xmax], ymax));
  label.lft("\begin{tabular}{c}Difference between\\Performance and\\Expectations\end{tabular}", (.5[xmin, u], .3ymin));
endfig;
end.
```

Output:

[image]